# Python regex- match a string like MGRoad to a sting like MG_Road

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to python and 
I want to match a pattern which comes from a list and if matches return the pattern.
List contains names of areas in a city and I need to find if a area is present in a url like

```
www.abc.com/category-city_area_name-deal/

city=[AreaName]
```

I need to match AreaName in the url regardless of underscore present in url. So for me when i search for AreaName in the url, it should match to area_name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore underscores and upper/lower case, you can try this without using regex:

```
url = "www.abc.com/category-city_area_name-deal/"
city = "AreaName"

if city.replace('_', '').lower() in url.replace('_', '').lower():
    print 'ok'
```

The `a.replace('_', '').lower()` removes all underscores from `a` and converts it to lowercase.

```
 city.replace('_', '').lower() -> 'areaname'
 url.replace('_', '').lower()  -> 'www.abc.com/category-cityareaname-deal/'
```

and then it tests whether `'areaname'` is contained within `'www.abc.com/category-cityareaname-deal/'`, which is True.